# Unable to pinpoint "Unexpected token '<EOF>'." error message with Apex REST callout

Tags: apex, callout

I can't seem to pinpoint where the issue is in my Apex REST callout that's causing the following error to appear during execution:

> Unexpected token '<EOF>'.

My code is as follows:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/*/')
global class AuthCallout {
    @HttpGet
    global static void basicAuthCallout(){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint('callout:/Sharepoint_Online/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx?client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx');
        req.setHeader('APIKEY', '{!$Sharepoint_Online.Password}');
        //req.setCompressed(true);
        HTTPResponse res = new Http().send(req);
        Document doc = new Document(Name='test.txt', Body=res.getBodyAsBlob(), FolderId='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        insert doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a compile issue or do you get the issue while you're running the code?

Comment: Not that I would expect it to cause the failure message you indicate, but I think the leading slash on your `setEndpoint` call is incorrect. I think it's supposed to be `setEndpoint('callout:Named_Credential_Name/path/to/resource?param=value')`.

Comment: It's an issue while running the code. I have '0' compile issues atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the

```
Body=res.getBodyAsBlob()
```

According to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_document.htm), the body field is base64 not blob. Try

```
String body = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(res.getBodyAsBlob());
Document doc = new Document(Name='test.txt', Body=body), FolderId='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

It's also a good idea to explicitly set the content type, use `text/plain` for .txt

### Update

There are two issues, the other issue is the URL mapping. It has an extra `/` in it. It should be `'/*'`

> If an '*' appears, it must be preceded by '/' and followed by '/', **unless the '*' is the last character, in which case it need not be followed by '/'** [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm)

Comment: I get a problem: "Illegal assignment from String to Blob" at the "String body = ..." line. Also is my URL Mapping sufficient at the top? I don't know how to frame it so I left it as a wildcard.

Comment: I'll need to see your code to figure out why you're getting that error, the code as I wrote it is as correct as I can make it.

Comment: Ok. I came across this reference (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) as well and tried to create a type Blob to store res.getbodyasblob(); but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: try something like `blob.valueOf(res.getBody())`

Comment: Hmm, that may have worked but the issue is now: Line 1, Col 29, Unexpected token '<EOF>' which points right to the asterick.

Comment: According to this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm You don't need the last / in your URL mapping, just `'/*'`

Comment: If you ever figure out what the issue was, post an answer to your own question so that other users will benefit @xorLogic

Comment: I think to resolve this one, I had to remove the decorators. Issue seemed to have resolved afterwards.